# Half installed package error

Tags: apt, dpkg

Received the following error when attempting to install from Terminal:

```
Selecting previously unselected package dassault-systemes-draftsight.
(Reading database … 211618 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking dassault-systemes-draftsight (from …/Downloads/draftSight.deb) …
access control disabled, clients can connect from any host
access control disabled, clients can connect from any host
access control disabled, clients can connect from any host
```

Now receiving system error notification that it's half installed and causing the error.
It's crashing the Software Center, I cannot figure out how to kill the offending `dpkg` or how to un-install what is installed to start over.

```
sudo apt-get remove dassult-systemes-draftsight
[sudo] password for user:
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?
```

Made a bit more progress:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: The package dassault-systemes-draftsight needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.
```

dpkg/Status shows half installed:

```
Package: dassault-systemes-draftsight
Status: install reinstreq half-installed
Priority: extra
Section: applications
Architecture: i386
Version: 2012.7.347
```

But Terminal says it's not there:

```
user:~$ sudo dpkg --force-remove-reinstreq --remove dassult-systemes-draftsight
dpkg: warning: ignoring request to remove dassult-systemes-draftsight which isn't installed
user@computer:~$ sudo dpkg -e DraftSight
dpkg-deb: error: failed to read archive `DraftSight': No such file or directory
```

Comment: when apt told you to reinstall, did you? `apt-get install dassault-systems-fraftsight --reinstall`

Answer (score 0):

First run :

```
sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock
```

Then:

```
sudo dpkg -r dassault-systems-fraftsight
```

If it is successful or not, then run

```
gksudo gedit /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

In the resulting Gedit, remove the whole section starts with :

`Package: dassault-systemes-draftsight`

Save and Close it.